# Giving an alternative Async method to a service

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have an interface, implemented by a service, that I inject here and there in my codebase.
I would like to give the opportunity to use either the normal method *or* its async equivalent.

```
public interface IServiceDoStuff
{
    void DoSomeHeavyWork();
    Task DoSomeHeavyWorkAsync();     
}
```

In my implementation I just do it like this

```
public class Service: IServiceDoStuff
{
    public void DoSomeHeavyWork(){ ... }

    public Task DoSomeHeavyWorkAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => { DoSomeHeavyWork();});
    }
}
```

So my consumers just go

```
await injectedService.DoSomeHeavyWorkAsync();
```

My question is simply : **is that a correct way to offer those two alternatives ?**

`Tasks`, `async` and `await` have been giving me headaches forever, as it has always been one of the most obscure .NET features I work with. I can never feel confident about the code I write using those features.

Comment: [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Comment: Please read these Stephen Toub's excellent articles about this topic: [async wrapper for sync](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/), [sync wrapper for async](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

Answer (score 2):

If your implementation does not create interrupts of some sort there is no point in making it async. If the consumer does not want to wait for your code to execute its better to let them control that and execute your code seperate from the main thread.

Edit: if the interface and implementation are shipped seperate or if its possible someone will replace default none async implementation with a async implementation. Than it could be a good practice to make the interface Async and in your default implementation return Task.FromResult or Task.CompletedTask.